# Tkinter global modules

Tags: python-3.x, testing, tkinter, global

*Hello!*

I've heard that the global function can lead to problems especially when debugging, so I'd like to know if anyone has an idea how to write the following python code the best way possible. Thanks in advance.

```
from tkinter import Tk, Label, ttk, Entry
win = Tk()
win.grid()
win.geometry('200x100')


def func():
    bt1.destroy()
    global inp_f
    inp_f = Entry(win)
    inp_f.grid(padx=38, pady=20)



def func1(event):
    try:
        print(str(inp_f.get()))
    except:
        print('Button not already attributed')


win.bind('<Return>', func1)

bt1 = ttk.Button(win, command=func, text='Login')
bt1.grid(padx=60, pady=20)


win.mainloop()
```

Comment: "best way possible" is incredibly subjective.

Comment: So in your mind, like i've done it's perfectly fine?

Comment: No, not saying that.  There are just many things to consider when determining what is "best".  Best for who/what?  Global variables, for example are generally good to avoid, but it doesn't mean you should never use them.  It is more about choosing the right tool for the specific job and understanding the consequences or limitations of those choices.

Comment: Use a class, or make it a global variable outside the function.

For something this small, a lot of code principles won't matter. However when your code grows bigger the principles importance will grow relative to the code.

Comment: Ok so to recap the global variable is to be avoided but in the case of simple program, if the code works there is no worries. @LBJ if I create this variable outside the function, my code will not be reactive, right?

Comment: @Flo.dev From experience the global keyword are either used by lazy programmers or new programmers which are unfamiliar with variable scope, functions and classes. The general rule is to refrain from using the global keyword, unless necessary or as last resort. Anyway the reason you want to refrain from using the global keyword is because it makes debugging harder, and it also clutters the name space for your variables. Neither is an issue in a project this small. However bad habits are hard to break, and it's generally advised to develop good habits as early as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to define what is the "best", it depends many things. I have written a possible solution for you. It's an OOP approach and it doesn't contain global variables/function (Of course, except the `my_app` variable).

The code contains many comment for the better understanding.

**Code:**

```
"""
Example application for TkInter.
"""

from tkinter import Tk, ttk, Entry


class MyApp(Tk):
    """
    The MyApp class is inherited from Tk from tkinter package.
    """

    # These are class variables. You can use them as "global variables" inside the class.
    # Perhaps you can put them to "__init__" method as well then they are instance variables.
    # The proper location of these variables depend on the usage of them.
    inp_f = None
    bt1 = None

    def __init__(self):
        """
        This is the constructor of the "MyApp" class. It's called when you create an instance from
        the class.
        Eg.:
            my_app = MyApp()
        """

        # You have to call the "__init__" method of the super class (Tk). There is not input
        # of the __init__ method so you shouldn't pass anything.
        super().__init__()

        # Set the required configurations. You can use the "self" to access the attributes of Tk.
        self.grid()
        self.geometry("200x100")
        self.bind("<Return>", self.func1)
        self.create_widgets()

    def func(self):
        """
        Your function (Otherwise it's method).
        Returns: None
        """

        # You can access to class variables with name of your class (MyApp)
        MyApp.bt1.destroy()
        MyApp.inp_f = Entry(self)
        MyApp.inp_f.grid(padx=38, pady=20)

    @staticmethod
    def func1(_):  # I use "_" as input parameter because it's not used in the method.
        """
        Your function

        Args:
            _: This is the event input.

        Returns: None
        """

        try:
            print(str(MyApp.inp_f.get()))
        except Exception:  # It's a too broad exception.
            print("Button not already attributed")

    def create_widgets(self):
        """
        Creating the widgets on the window.
        Returns: None
        """

        MyApp.bt1 = ttk.Button(self, command=self.func, text="Login")
        MyApp.bt1.grid(padx=60, pady=20)


# Create an instance from your class.
my_app = MyApp()

# Call the "mainloop" method of our class.
my_app.mainloop()
```

**Console:**

```
>>> python3 test.py

Button not already attributed
Button not already attributed
foo
foo
```

**GUI:**

[image: First]

[image: Second]

Comment: *"it doesn't contain global variables"* Note that `my_app` is *global variable*.

Comment: Sure, It's a global variable but it's the variable to start the application so I guess it's not really in scope of problematic global object usage (And probably it's used only in global scope to start the application and not in nested way). :) On the other hand, Thanks for you notice, I am precising my answer.